# New column value from column name indicated in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have been banging my head against the wall all day on this one, so I'm hoping someone can help with this.

Here is some test code:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [-1, -2, -3]})
test['C'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A'])
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    test.loc[row.name, 'D'] = row[row['C']]
```

Essentially I need to create a new column in my pandas dataframe, but I need the value stored in each row to be determined by a string value contained within another row. This would mean it pulls the value from a different column for each row. The above code works, however it needs to iterate through the rows, meaning as my data size increases over time so would my runtime.

Ideally I would like to use a vectorized approach, but so far I haven't been able to crack this one.

So the input dataframe looks like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  1 -1  A
1  2 -2  B
2  3 -3  A
```

And I'd like the output to look like this

```
   A  B  C   D
0  1 -1  A   1
1  2 -2  B  -2
2  3 -3  A   3
```

Notice that each value in column D comes from the corresponding row in the column indicated in column C. So the first value in D is the first value of columnA because the first value of column C is "A"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the values in C as column names. So you won't need to iterate over the rows at all:

```
In [149]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [-1, -2, -3]})                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [150]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[150]: 
   A  B
0  1 -1
1  2 -2
2  3 -3

In [151]: df['C'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'A'])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [152]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[152]: 
   A  B  C
0  1 -1  A
1  2 -2  B
2  3 -3  A

In [153]: df['D'] = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [154]: for val in df.C.unique(): df.loc[df.C==val, 'D'] = df[val]                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [155]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[155]: 
   A  B  C   D
0  1 -1  A   1
1  2 -2  B  -2
2  3 -3  A   3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much.